# How to set string while running the code?

Tags: python, console, console-application

So I trying do make a simple console application with python but I have a problem.
Im trying to make a new "write" command. This command will print a text.

example:

```
> write hello
> hello
```

But I dont know how to make this. Here the command in my code:

```
x = ""

if w == "write " + x:
    
    if x == "":

        print("you need to add words")

    if x != "":

        print(x)
```

This is an annoying and I need the help to solve this

Comment: What's the value of `w` ?

Comment: The `w` is the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a while loop like so:

```
while True:
    w = input("> ")
    if w.startswith('write '):
        print(w.split(' ', 1)[1])
```

Test run:

```
> write hello
hello
> write bye bye
bye bye
> hey hi
> help please!
> write Help please!
Help please!
>
```

Comment: This works, as long as there are no whitespaces in the string that should be printed.

Comment: You are right. My bad! I think this solution should be the accepted answer. Actually your answer is awesome! I learned something new! Never knew, I could add a parameter to split :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

use the `sys.argv[]` list. its easier and straitforward:

`sys.argv` is a `list` in Python, which contains the command-line arguments passed to the script.

pay attention `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script itself!

so the easieaset way to do it is by the built in `sys.argv list`. for example if my script is called : `foo.py`, i can pass to it arguments via command line like so:

python foo.py write hello
and in foo.py ican get the passed argument like so:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        #do work with arg! arg is a string type!
        if argv[1]=='write':
            print(argv[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `input()` to accept user input at the keyboard, and `split()` to separate the input into sections:

```
command = input("Enter a command >")
parts = command.split(maxsplit=1)
if parts[0] == "write":
    if len(parts) > 1:
        print(parts[1])
    else:
        print("you did not enter any words to write")
else:
    print("unknown command")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to write an application that does not take the command as
parameters on calling it (as suggested in answered above), but you run the program and in a loop check the user input, you could do it the following way:

```
import re 

def main():
    user_input = input()
    write_command_pattern = "(?<=write)\s+.*"

    result = re.findall(write_command_pattern, user_input)
    print(result[0])

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The regular expression `(?<=write)\s+.*` returns every arbitrary string preceded by `write`. for taking multiple commands, you may wrap that in a loop and add other patterns for other commands.